# Return words with characters [a,b,b,c]

Tags: java, hashmap

Given a list of strings `["abc", "abcdb", "gggh", "klsrtabcabc", "118*90", "ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"]`

Return words which contain all letters from `[a,b,b,c]`.(This means words with, at least, 'a' one time, 'b' two times, and 'c' one time)

Answer: "abcdb", "klsrtabcabc"

This is the hashmap algorithm for this

1. Build a character frequency map from the list of required characters. E.g. for `[a,b,b,c]` you end up with `{a=1, b=2, c=1}`
2. Iterate the list of strings:

> 1. Build a character frequency map from the string. E.g. for "klsrtabcabc" you end up with `{a=2, b=2, c=2, k=1, l=1, r=1, s=1, t=1}`
> 2. Check if string has at least the required number of characters. E.g. since a: 2 >= 1, b: 2 >= 2, and c: 2 >= 1, the string is selected.
> 3. If selected, add the string to the result.
>    3. Return the list of results.

I converted the first step into java code as shown as below, can anyone help me with step 2 and 3?

```java
package JavaInterview;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class practice {
    
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str1="abbc";

    //1. Build a character frequency map from the list of required characters.
            
    Map<Character,Integer> hm=new LinkedHashMap<Character,Integer>();
       
    for(Character c : str1.toCharArray()) {
      if(hm.containsKey(c)) {
        hm.put(c, hm.get(c)+1);
      }
                
      else {
        hm.put(c, 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you be more precise about what problem you're facing?  You've done a great job of explaining the goal you have, but you haven't given a specific issue for us to address.

Comment: @zcoop98, i dont know how to write code for step 2 (step 2  has 3 additional steps as well) and step 3,from where i will get the java code for it.please help

Comment: Please try writing the Java code yourself. I mentioned the approach as an answer. SO is mainly for solving any issues if you are stuck. If you are new to Java and want to learn then please have a read and try to implement the approach I mentioned. After trying if you are still stuck then please paste what you tried so that we can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should try the steps 2 and 3 and come to SO when you are stuck with an issue and you can't find an answer. For now, I will give you my approach - Just a pseudocode:

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
     Map<Character,Integer> temp = hm;
     for(Character c : arr[i].toCharArray())
     {
         if(!temp.containsKey(c) or temp[c]<=0)
            break the loop;
         else
            temp[c]--;
     }
     if(end of arr[i] charArray)
            answer.add(arr[i]);
}
```